# saving image from website and putting it into a sqlite database in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I'm trying to save a photo given a URL and put it directly into a sqlite database without saving it in permanent memory.

Currently, the code I have to save the image is:

```
 file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg")
 output = open('filename.jpg','wb')
 output.write(file.read())
 output.close()
```

Is there a way to store it in temporary memory so it's not permanently saved?

Once I have the file stored, how do I actually store it in the database?

Sorry for the lack of programming terminology.

Comment: A non-permanent database does not make much sense. What do you intend to do with the image in the database?

Comment: Sorry, I mean save it permanently in the database, but not save it permanently outside of the database. The only way I know how to do it now is to save the file to my computer, then upload it to the database, but how would I skip that intermediary step?

Answer (score 0):

The data you want is already returned by `file.read()`.
You just have to put this data into the database:

```
file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg")
db.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn) VALUES(?)", [buffer(file.read())]
db.commit()
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks so much! What does the question mark do in 'VALUES(?)' ? Also am I correct that it has to be a BLOB datatype? Thanks!

Comment: [Parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam). SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).